# error expected primary expression before

Tags: c++, compilador

me sale un error que no entiendo al compilar un codigo, este es el código: (la funcion es privada)

```
void  gr_simplificada::erase_epsilon(set<char> h){
        set<produccion>::iterator it;
        set<char>::iterator itset;
        for(itset=h.begin();itset!=h.end();itset++){
            for(it=gr_simplificada.producciones_.begin();it!=gr_simplificada.producciones_.end();it++){
                if((*itset)==((*it).get_noterminales())){
                    for(int k =0 ;k<(*it).get_regla().size();k++){
                        for(int q=0; q<(*it).get_regla()[k].size();q++){
                            char objetivo = (*it).get_regla()[k][q];
                            if(objetivo=="~"){
                                (*it).get_regla().erase(k);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el error que no entiendo:

```
GR_SIMPLIFICADA.cpp:196:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
             for(it=gr_simplificada.producciones_.begin();it!=gr_simplificada.producciones_.end();it++){
                                   ^
GR_SIMPLIFICADA.cpp:196:77: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
             for(it=gr_simplificada.producciones_.begin();it!=gr_simplificada.producciones_.end();it++){
```

La función elimina forma parte de un algoritmo de eliminacion de producciones vacias de una gramática independiente del contexto

GRacias

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el tipo (`gr_simplificada`) con un valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo `gr_simplificada` es un tipo, pero tú estás usando el nombre del objeto como instancia. Dado que estás en un método miembro, no necesitas anteponer nada para acceder a las variables miembro:

```
//    vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <-- esto es el tipo!
void  gr_simplificada::erase_epsilon(set<char> h){
    set<produccion>::iterator it;
    set<char>::iterator itset;
    for(itset=h.begin();itset!=h.end();itset++){
        for(it=/*gr_simplificada.*/producciones_.begin();it!=/*gr_simplificada.*/producciones_.end();it++){
//             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    <-- innecesario -->   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            if((*itset)==((*it).get_noterminales())){
                for(int k =0 ;k<(*it).get_regla().size();k++){
                    for(int q=0; q<(*it).get_regla()[k].size();q++){
                        char objetivo = (*it).get_regla()[k][q];
                        if(objetivo=="~"){
                            (*it).get_regla().erase(k);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```